# ksh equivalent for environment variable Bash PROMPT_COMMAND

Tags: bash, variables, ksh

In bash, I have tried defining PROMPT_COMMAND="./sample_script" in ~/.bashrc file. Everytime I press enter, the sample_script is executed. But, when I tried to do the same in ~/.kshrc, it only works once i.e. when I login on a terminal. But after that, the succeeding press of enter key does not execute the ./sample_script. So it seems that there is a specific equivalent for this variable.

Is there a ksh equivalent of PROMPT_COMMAND (bash)?  Please help me. Many thanks!

Btw, i am new here and this is my first post. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function prompt_command {
    date
}
PS1='$(prompt_command)'
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Ipor ! It worked! I just made minor adjustment so that the original value/declaration of PS1 will also be retained.  

function prompt_command  
{  
        ~/ss  
}  

PS1='$(prompt_command)K:!> '  
[ "$TERM" = "vt100"           ] && PS1="$LOGNAME@$HOSTNAME:$PS1"  
[ "$TERM" = "xterm"           ] && PS1="$LOGNAME@$HOSTNAME:$PS1"  
[ "$TERM" = "dtterm"          ] && PS1="$LOGNAME@$HOSTNAME:$PS1"

Comment: I just learned we cannot add line breaks here in comment section..

Comment: Why is history command not working when I try to integrate with PS1 through the function prompt_command? I wanted to log the command issued everytime the Enter key is pressed